# How do you prevent undefined amounts of texts from going outside the the tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and I am trying to create a word finder using the PyDictionary module. But this led to the problem of definitions spilling out of the fixed windows after you insert the word you want to find out. This is kind of confusing since not every definition has same amount of description. What should I do?

code:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import tkinter as tk

dictionary = PyDictionary()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Word Finder")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
root.maxsize(400, 300)
root.minsize(400, 300)
canvas1.pack()

title = tk.Label(root, text="Word Finder")
canvas1.create_window(200, 100, window=title)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)


def getSquareRoot():
    x1 = entry1.get()

    try:
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text=dictionary.meaning(x1))
    except UnboundLocalError:
        label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Word Not Found")
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)


button1 = tk.Button(text='Search', command=getSquareRoot)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify your example to use a small subset of hard-coded data rather than using an external module?

Comment: Use `Text` widget instead of `Label` widget for the result.